# How to split 4 folders of dataset to different folders in python?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I was trying one of the CNN tutorials for shape Image classification using python. I have 4 folders of different shapes. I try the following code to split the dataset.

```
os.mkdir(os.path.join(path_target, 'train'))
os.mkdir(os.path.join(path_target, 'valid'))
for t in ['train', 'valid']:
    for folder in ['circle/', 'square/', 'star/', 'triangle/']:
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(path_target, t, folder))
```

```
def preprocessData(dirName, ext):
    allFiles = list()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirName):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(ext):
                allFiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    Shuffle(allFiles)Split = 0.7
    split_index = floor(len(allFiles) * split)
    training = allFiles[:split_index]
    testing = allFiles[split_index:]
    return training, testing
```

But I get the following error

```
  File "<ipython-input-29-6be535540069>", line 8
    Shuffle(allFiles)Split =0.7
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to split the datasets folder wise in python?

Comment: Sure, but your error is exactly what it says: `invalid syntax`. Please explain what that line `Shuffle(allFiles)Split =0.7` is supposed to do.

Comment: It's supposed to shuffles and splits datasets into a ratio of 70:30.

Comment: That's not valid python code. I'm gonna post a guess what your intention might have been as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random    

def preprocessData(dirName, ext):
    allFiles = list()
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirName):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(ext):
                allFiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    random.shuffle(allFiles)
    split = 0.7
    split_index = floor(len(allFiles) * split)
    training = allFiles[:split_index]
    testing = allFiles[split_index:]
    return training, testing
```